# Simple htaccess base rewrite for site in subfolder, links with relative paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I want to put up a site for demo purposes in a subfolder on my server, where all links are using relative paths (i.e. starting with "/"). This defaults back to the root folder, the easiest way to solve this would probably be to set up a htaccess file. I just cant seem to get it right. Am I missing something here? I've tested and made sure mod_rewrite is enabled inside the folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mydemo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all your web scripts, php, html, css, image files in `mydemo/` folder and have this .htaccess in **site root**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!mydemo/)(.*)$ mydemo/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that there is another site in the main root folder which uses .htaccess. It probably affects this subsite if I dont override it locally? It should probably go in a separate file?

Comment: You can place `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]` before this rule to make sure this rule executes for a given domain name only.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this is all under the same domain? You mean like thissite.com/mydemo

Comment: You wrote: `Thanks! I forgot to mention that there is another site in the main root folder` so clearly you have more one sites to support. Isn't it?

Comment: I believe for the site that you want to demo, you have a different domain e.g. `demosite.com`